# how i can delete multiple record or objects in django?

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I want to delete multiple records using html checkbox but i don't get any idea how i perform this task. At this time in my project I implement the single delete record or object through generic views as you can see in below code.

How i can delete multiple records using checkbox?
what changes i need to do in my code?

All code Edited with traceback error  @ruddra

**views.py**

```
class DeleteProducts(SuccessMessageMixin, View):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('stock:stock')
    success_message = "Products {} are deleted successfully."

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = self.request.POST.getlist('product')
        products_deleted = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=products).delete()
        msg = self.success_message.format(', '.join(products_deleted))
        messages.success(self.request, msg, extra_tags='alert-danger')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

**urls.py**

```
      path('delete', login_required(DeleteProducts.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='deleteproducts'),
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
  <h2 class="text-center" ><i>Stock!</i></h2>
    {% if messages %}
    {%for message in messages%}
        <div class="alert {{ message.tags }}" role="alert">
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  <hr/>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'stock:deleteproducts' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  {% for product in page_obj %}

  <div class="row" >
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{ product.id }}">
    <div class="col-sm-2" >
          <h5>{{ product.id }}</h5>
          <img src="{{ product.Picture.url }}" height="120px"  />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" >
      <h5><u>Product Name</u>: {{ product.pro_name }}</h5>
      <h6><u>Company Name</u>: {{product.companyName}}</h6>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm" >
           <p>Purchase Price: <b>{{product.Purchase_Price}}</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm" >
          <p class="pt-0">Sale Price: <b>{{product.Sale_Price}}</b> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-sm" >
           <p>Quantity <b>{{product.Quantity}}</b></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm" >
          <p> Added By:  <b>{{product.saler}}</b> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="col-sm-4" >
         <p><b>Added Date</b>:{{ product.pub_date }}</p>
         <hr/>
         <center>
           <a href="{% url 'stock:editproduct' product.id %}" class="btn btn-success" >Edit</a>

         </center>

    </div>

  </div>
  <hr/>

  {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" >
</form>
    <div class="pagination " >
        <div class="step-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page=1" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">&laquo; first</a>
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">previous</a>
            {% endif %}


            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success " >next</a>
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" >last &raquo;</a>
            {% endif %}
            <br/>
                <div
                        class="current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>



</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**traceback**

```
Internal Server Error: /stock/delete
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Adil Ijaz\Desktop\onlineProject\market\stock\views.py", line 131, in post
    msg = self.success_message.format(', '.join(products_deleted))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can't do that with [**`DeleteView`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView) as it expects one instance to be deleted. For that, you need to create a new view. Like this:

```
from django.views import View
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class DeleteProducts(SuccessMessageMixin, View):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('stock:stock')
    success_message = "Products {} are deleted successfully."

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        products = self.request.POST.getlist('product')
        products_deleted = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=products).delete()
        msg = self.success_message.format(', '.join(map(str, products_deleted)))
        messages.success(self.request, msg, extra_tags='alert-danger')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.success_url)
```

Then update the url:

```
path('delete', login_required(DeleteProducts.as_view(), login_url='login'), name='deleteproducts'),
```

And in template:

```
<form method="POST" action={% url 'deleteproducts' %}>
```

I am using [**`request.POST.getlist`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get multiple items(or product ids) from post request.

Comment: `sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found` facing this error

Comment: how i paste all whole traceback error at here in comment section?@ruddra

Comment: you need to update your question with the traceback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211076/discussion-between-adil-ijaz-and-ruddra).

Comment: Updated answer should fix the issue @AdilIjaz can you try that?

Comment: yes i tried but I'm facing this error `sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found`

Comment: that error should not persist. can you delete *.pyc files, then restart the server and try again please?

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you @ruddra...there is a mistake in html file i miss the attribute `name='product'`